# TP-Link TL-SG2210P 3.20 Firmware won't upgrade

Tags: switch, firmware

The TP-Link TL-SG2210P, hardware version 3.20 (and maybe others) has an issue where a firmware upgrade will fail with an unhelpful error message (Failed to upgrade the firmware. Please try again.)

I was unable to find anything in logs relating to the error.

The current firmware version is from 2020 and I want to upgrade to the latest monthly release (it is now December 2022).

Answer (score 4):

The below worked for me. Simply download and install 20210407 first, then you can upgrade directly to the latest.

Information found in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TpLink/comments/potu10/need_help_tlsg2210p_320_firmware_wont_upgrade/).

The notes for the 20210806 firmware are correct, one does indeed need to install the 20210407 release first.

Unfortunately, the 20210407 firmware is not easy to find.

Instead of being located on (or linked to from the) default [download page for the TL-SG2210P V3.2](https://www.tp-link.com/fi/support/download/tl-sg2210p/v3.20/) the 20210407 firmware is on a [different page](https://www.tp-link.com/eg/support/download/tl-sg2210p/v3/#Firmware).